# How to solve this non-linear, second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

does anyone know how to solve this ODE?

$ yy'' +y' +y =0 $

where y is a function of one real variable.

Comment: First step is to divide by $y$ and integrate up $y'' = -1 - y'/y$ using $(y'/y) = (\log(y))'$

Comment: @Winther Why not make that an answer in the form of a hint?

Comment: i think there is no explicit solution

Comment: @Winther, I have figured out already how to reduce it to a first order ODE 

$y' + \mathrm{ln}y = -t + K$

where $y$ depends on $t$ and $K$ is an arbitrary constant, but I don't then know how to solve this!